# How to implement a data model in iOS that can handle multiple API calls?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and iOS programming in general.
Currently I am developing an app which makes API calls and fetches data and displays them.

So Im using a GET request to fetch data, so for example ,

```
www.example.com/city1 would give the details of city1 ,   
www.example.com/city2 would give the details of city 2 and so on.
```

After I get the data , I parse them and extract the required fields from the JSON.

---

**My question**

I have a screen in which I have to display the same parameter for different cities.

**Ex**: My screen 2, has Eight UI labels and each label should display the same information(Temperature) from different cities.

The only change is the city name parameter which I send in the GET request when I make the API call. I have implemented the GET request using Alamofire in a separate Swift file in the project.
So what is the best way to implement the same?
Im using Swift 3 for the above project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Alamofire

struct City {

    //eight fields
    let name: String


    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        // init and check required fields
        if let name = json["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func fetchCity(for id: String, success: @escaping (City) -> Void, fail: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("wwww.example.com/\(id)").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                fail(error)
            }

            if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                if let city = City(json: json) {
                     success(city)
                }

                //Missing required fields
                fail(customError)
            }
        }
    }
}



City.fetchCity(for: "city1", success: { city in

}, fail: { error in

})
```

You might use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for parse json response